# Casting Problem On DatagridViewtextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have noticed that DatagridviewtextBoxColumn is not casting to Decimal. I have demonstrate it by two ways which are as follows.

1. **DataTable** :-

   ```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("carats");
   dt.Columns.Add("rate");
   dt.Columns.Add("amount");
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   ```

It works  fine with Following casting code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  int b = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
  if (
       dataGridView1[0, b].Value != DBNull.Value && 
       dataGridView1[1, b].Value !=    DBNull.Value
     )
  {
    dataGridView1[2, b].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[0, b].Value.ToString())          
    * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, b].Value.ToString());

  }
}
```

But my main observation on DatagridviewtextBoxColumn it’s notcasting  it Why?.

2.**DatagridviewtextboxColumn**:-

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cts = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();              
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, cts);
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn rt = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, rt);
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn amt = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, amt);
```

It’s Throw Error Like **“NullReference Exception was Unhandle”, “Object reference not set an instance on an Object “**  with Following Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  int b = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
  if (
       dataGridView1[0, b].Value != DBNull.Value && 
       dataGridView1[1, b].Value !=    DBNull.Value
     )
  {
    dataGridView1[2, b].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[0, b].Value.ToString())          
    * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, b].Value.ToString());

  }
}
```

**I just wants to know the reason behind it. And Solve the Casting Problem with DatagridviewtextBoxColumn**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used only 'null' to check datagridView cells, not DBNull. Have you tried with that?

Edit: after reading a bit I found [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=508094) (VB.NET) which says that

> If the grid is bound to a DataTable then "empty" cells will contain DBNull.Value. If the grid is bound to something else or not bound at all then "empty" cells will contain Nothing

so you should probably check for null.

Comment: @Rox, yes you are right but why it's works with datatable and why not with datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?

Comment: Doesn't it work after changing to null in the datagridview? DBNull is used only for DataTable binding - I don't know why it's this way, but maybe you can find more on msdn

Comment: @mahesh: In the first example you've bound the `DataGridView` to a `DataTable`, so empty cells have a value of `DBNull` (on which you can call `ToString` without a `NullReferenceException`) whereas in the second example the `DataGridView` is unbound, so what Rox is pointing out is that empty cells contain `null`. If you call `null.ToString()` you get a `NullReferenceException`. So you need to change `!= DBNull.Value` to `!= null`.

Comment: @Rox, it is works with datagridviewtextboxcoulmn and it is not working with datatable.

Comment: You use DBNull for the first example (bound DataTable) and null for the datagridview. You can't have the same for both.

Comment: @Dan, oh! yes DBNull is working only with bound dgv by datatable it's not support to unbound dgv. thanks for help. @Rox I hereby accept with you. thanks.